# cannot get tag however it is appear on html

Tags: html, css, web-scraping

I am trying a scraping job using BeatifulSoup and find methods, I get the HTML with lxml parser as following :

```
result  =  requests.get('https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/xgUqkfYngXZL-Senior-Python-Developer-Remote---Part-Time-Cairo-Egypt?o=2&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|hpb')
#print(result.status_code)
soup1 =BeautifulSoup(result.content , "html5lib")
sections  = soup1.find( 'section' ,class_="css-3kx5e2")
divs = sections.find_all('div')
spans = sections.find_all('span')
span = divs[3].find('span' , class_ ='css-47jx3m')
divs[3]
```

I get the following

```
<div class="css-rcl8e5"><span class="css-wn0avc">Salary<!-- -->:</span></div>
```

however, the original HTML is

```
<div class="css-rcl8e5"><span class="css-wn0avc">Salary<!-- -->:</span>
<span class="css-47jx3m"><span class="css-8il94u">Confidential, Hourly Based</span>
</span>
</div>
```

I need to get the ('span class="css-8il94u"') which have the text ('Confidential, Hourly Based') but it does not appear

thanks

Comment: "however, the original HTML is" — No, it isn't. You must be looking at the page in a DOM inspector… after it has been modified by JS.

Comment: i check it still  i need to get the salary values ( Confidential, Hourly Based ) using my code

Comment: As it is a dynamic webpage, ie, javascript is inserting code in it after load, so your parser is not able to find the specific data, One thing you can do is use Selenium to open the webpage and then scrape the page for content. Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-content-from-dynamic-websites/

Comment: I gathering all data except this, the site is not a dynamic one, I agree with you if there are dynamic sites the data will not be scraping using Beatifulsoup as my code but this site, not a dynamic one